# Multi Step form with results from previous action shown on top (with ability to edit)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I really did search.

What I'm trying to do is to make a form which asks questions over a couple of pages, and each time I go to the next page, the Input from the previous page gets placed on top of the page with the ability to edit.

---

Please choose a date:
|DATE INPUT|

|NEXT|

---

Date: 28/07/2011              CHANGE

Please choose a category:

- CAT A
- CAT B
- CAT C

|NEXT|

---

Date: 28/07/2011    CHANGE
Category: CAT B     CHANGE

And so on and so on.
Thaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
<style>

.question {
    display: none;
}
.question.active,.question.answered {
    display: block;
}
.question.answered input {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div class="question active">Q1<input type="text"></div>
<div class="question new">Q2<input type="text"></div>
<div class="question new">Q3<input type="text"></div>
<div class="question new">Q4<input type="text"></div>
<button id="NEXT">NEXT</button>

<script>
$('button#NEXT').click(function() {
    $('.question.active').removeClass('active').addClass('answered');
    $('.question.new').first().addClass('active').removeClass('new');
})
</script>
```

that is demo : http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/z9hDm/

Comment: Hmmm that's one way to do it. Thank you :)

Comment: Can I, for example change this so that if Q1 was a checkbox, that the next form after that would change depending on what was picked before? And if so, let's say that I got to the last question and then decided to change the first checkbox to something else, then how would I "delete" all of the DIV INPUTS that come after question 1 (because answers after question 1 depend on what was chosen)?

Comment: you can do anything I just give a basic sample, you can load things using jQuery.post(), etc giving more sample will requere much work, what i can say - make that checks in that click routiine and change values as you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can work here with session and numerated pages.

After posting first page, save it to `$_SESSION['page1']`

If you'll count pages, you can convert it to:

```
$_SESSION['page' . $currentPage]
```

and then printing will be a piece of cake:

```
for ( $i = 1; $i < $currentPage; $i++ ) {
    $data = $_SESSION['page' . $currentPage];
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty complicated for a n00b like me, but I will search for what you said on google to learn more. Thanks!